# Facebook og:image is never detected

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When pasting a link to share of Facebook, I want a particular image to show up, not just a random image from my website. I have the following meta tag in my HTML:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.squeeboo.com/Squeeboo-main-logo.jpg">
```

Now for whatever reason, FB doesn't detect this. When I go the the url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and type in my website address, under "When shared, this is what will be included" the image shows up. However, this NOT what shows when pasted onto Facebook.

What am I missing? =/

Comment: What is your website address? For `https://www.squeeboo.com/` the debug tool currently shows errors about a circular redirect path, that you will need to fix first if you want this to work as expected.

Comment: The problem with the circular redirect. The index.php file in the root directory redirects to /homepage/index.php so changing the og:image property to https://www.squeeboo.com/homepage/ fixed the problem =)

Answer (score 0):

Your image is quadratic, use a proper one:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.

and:

> You should use a 1.91:1 image ratio, such as 600 x 314 px

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: _“Your image is quadratic”_ – that in itself should not be a problem though, as long as it is at least 200×200 pixels in size it should still be shown. (The recommended dimensions and aspect ratio are to help that it gets shown as a large picture, instead of a small, quadratic, possibly cropped one.)

Comment: in general, yes. but i did have some pages where a quadratic one did not work at all. but then again, the whole linting and caching is extremely buggy and does not really return good error messages...